# How does the technique work to calculate a system of ODEs (in form of a matrix) with the help of the matrix exponential?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I literally cannot find a tutorial to this anywhere, I'll be grateful if someone could elaborate this to me

I'm looking for the nonhomogeneous form, X' = AX + B(t)

Comment: You've been asking about this. What happens in dimension  1? Do $x' - x = \sin t$

Comment: I'm asking about the technique which requires the use of a matrix exponential